# Distributed Hash Tables. Do I need shortcuts (even in a large system)?

Tags: dht

I am learning about DHT and I came upon shortcuts. It seems they are used to make the routing faster and skip going directly back-the-chain for better performance. What I don't understand is: Suppose we have a circular DHT made out of 100 servers/nodes/HT. You get some key data to server/node/HT 10 and it must be sent to server/node/HT 76. When the destination is reached, and the value is taken couldn't I just provide the IP of the requester (server 10) and then it will directly send the value to 10, which seems to make shortcuts useless?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Useless for returning the value. Not getting to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming a circular network layout and forwading-based routing. Both of which only apply to a subset of DHTs.

Anyway, the forward path would still go through all the nodes, any of which might be down or have transient network problems. As the number of hops goes up so does the cumulative error probability. Additionally it increases latency, which matters on a global scale because at least simple DHT routing algorithms don't account for physical proximity.

For the return it can also matter if reachability is asymmetrical, e.g. due to firewalls.